# How to modify the XMLHTTPRequest header sent by another extension in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I add a listener to modify HTTP Headers like below in my chrome extension:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(my_listener, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
```

Normally, it will capture every HTTP request sent by the web pages, but it doesn't work when another chrome extension send a request with XMLHTTPRequest.

What the other extension does:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com/');
xhr.send()
```

Comment: 1. What is the `"permissions"` key in manifest.json? 2. Maybe that XHR url starts with `chrome-extension://`?

Comment: This is my permissions:
"permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "cookies",
        "notifications",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/"
    ],
And the XHR url starts with http://. I have captured it in console.

Comment: Apparently it's possible to view XHR originating in your own extension and webpages. I've tried adding `"chrome-extension://*/*"` permission but it didn't solve the problem, so maybe it's restricted for security reasons or just not yet implemented.